# Azure Server, ,"ExceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException" C#, SQL Server, works on localhost, not on server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, api, azure

I am calling WebAPI C# Get method but I got a strange error which occurs only when the application is running on the `Production`. When the application is working on the local there is no error. This is the error:

> at Application.Controllers.PostRelatedControllers.WallPostController.Get(Int32 skip, Int32 take, Boolean isProfile, String otherid) in E:\Programming\BetFray\Application\Controllers\PostRelatedControllers\WallPostController.cs:line 35
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
>   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.d__2.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.AuthenticationFilterResult.d__0.MoveNext()
>   ↵--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   ↵   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"

This is the method which I suspect is throwing the error:

```
var query = Set.Where(x => x.IsGroupPost == false && ((x.IsPostPrivate.Value  && frineds.Contains(x.UserID)) || !x.IsPostPrivate.Value)).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostId).AsNoTracking();
```

This is the `WallPostCore`'s   method:

```
public List<WallPostViewModel> GetWallPosts(int skip, int take, bool isProfile, string otherid, string userid)
{
    WallPostViewRepository wallPostViewRepository = new WallPostViewRepository();
    RelationshipsRepository relationshipsRepository = new RelationshipsRepository();
    List<WallPostView> posts;

    if (isProfile)
    {
        bool isOwnProfile = (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(otherid) && otherid != userid) ? true : false;

        if (isOwnProfile)
        {
            posts = wallPostViewRepository.GetOwn(skip, take, userid).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            var relationships = (userid == null) ? null : relationshipsRepository.FindFirstRelationShipIfExist(userid, otherid);

            if (relationships != null)
                posts = (relationships.AcceptedDate != null && relationships.Friend)
                        ? wallPostViewRepository.GetOwn(skip, take, otherid).ToList()
                        : wallPostViewRepository.GetOtherProfileNoFriends(skip, take, otherid).ToList();
            else
                posts = wallPostViewRepository.GetOtherProfileNoFriends(skip, take, otherid).ToList();
        }
    }
    else if(userid == null)
    {
        posts = wallPostViewRepository.GetLatestPublic(skip, take).ToList();
    }
    else
    {
        var relationships = relationshipsRepository.GetListOfFriends(userid).Where(x => x.AcceptedDate != null);
        var friendsIds = relationships.AsParallel().Where(x => x.Friend).GetNotMe(userid).Select(x => x.UserID).ToList();
        friendsIds.Add(userid);

        posts = wallPostViewRepository.GetLatest(skip, take, friendsIds).ToList();
    }            

    var userIds = posts.Select(x => x.UserID).Distinct().ToList();
    var userStats = GenerateUserStats(wallPostViewRepository.Context, userIds);
    var convertedPosts = posts.Select(x => x.SoftConvert(userStats, userid)).ToList();
    var postIds = posts.Select(x => x.PostId);

    GenerateWallPosts(wallPostViewRepository.Context, convertedPosts, postIds, userIds, userid);

    return convertedPosts.ToList();
}
```

This is the WallPostController

```
 [Authorize]
public class WallPostController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet]
    public List<WallPostViewModel> Get(int skip, int take, bool isProfile, string otherid)
    {
        WallpostCore core = new WallpostCore();
        try
        {
            var userid = User.Identity.GetUserId();

            var posts = core.GetWallPosts(skip, take, isProfile, otherid, userid);
            return posts;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                Content = new StringContent(e.StackTrace + "" + e.Message + " " + e.StackTrace +
                                            "inner exception " + e.InnerException.Message + "\n" +
                                            "second inner" +
                                            e.InnerException.InnerException.Message),
            };
            throw new HttpResponseException(resp);
        }
    }
```

End line 35 is: `var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound)`

Comment: Please post code for `WallPostController` and also indicate on which line the error is throw (highlight line 35)

Comment: Thank you for the quick replay, I just put the WallPostController

Comment: which line is line 35

Comment: The question is that the same request works on localhost but not working on production

Comment: check your web.config file on the server and see if it contains the connection string. If not then that's the problem. Looks like the Authorized attribute tag is the one throwing it

Comment: var resp = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound) This is line: 35

Comment: @vasilnedelchev please post the entire method including attribute tag that line 35 belongs to (in WallPostController.cs)

Comment: sorry for the confusion now I upload the controller with the line 35:

Comment: The connection string is fine since everything else is working. This is the only method I found is not working var query = Set.Where(x => x.IsGroupPost == false && ((x.IsPostPrivate.Value  && frineds.Contains(x.UserID)) || !x.IsPostPrivate.Value)).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostId).AsNoTracking();

Comment: when this method for example is called is working just fine: var query = Set.Where(x => x.UserID == userid && x.IsGroupPost == false && !x.IsPostPrivate.Value).OrderByDescending(x => x.PostId).AsNoTracking();

Comment: Only you can debug a null reference exception. We can't run your code. The failing line includes the object initializer, so my bet is that `e.InnerException.InnerException` doesn't always exist.

Answer (score 0):

First you should NEVER return the full server exception stack trace back to the client. This is extremely dangerous. You should always log the error in the DB.

Second you should never reconstruct the exception message that way. Just call `.ToString()` and it will provide everything you are trying to do

Your problem is at

```
e.InnerException.InnerException.Message
```

If the exception doesn't have a first or second level of inner exception this call will error out with a Null Ref

Comment: Thank you for the response. I got what you mean but this is not the problem because I had the same error without it. Later on, I added that piece of code.

Comment: @vasilnedelchev you need to get the new error msg with .ToString() and the new line number in this case